# React native- Creating 2 buttons/tabs that display different content?

Tags: react-native

How would I go by creating these 2 buttons/tabs in react native that display different content? They are supposed to be in the middle of the screen.

Something like in this [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JgT8.jpg)

Comment: show your code you have been doing

Comment: https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#segment-inside-header-headref you can use segments provided by native base library